# Split by two or more spaces

Tags: c#, regex

Lets say I have a string like this:

```
"15    Lore ipsum"
```

Is there a way to split it so I got 3 strings after split `["15", "Lore", "Ipsum"]`. So I want delimiter to be a space consisting of two or more spaces, I don't want one space to be delimiter...

Comment: How many spaces are in between Lore and Ipsum? One?

Comment: @Fred the accepted answer to the question i linked is `Regex.Split( stringvalue, @"\s{2,}")` which splits by *two or more spaces*, as the op asked. Also, as @Ian pointed out, I see one space between "Lore" and "ipsum"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `string.Split(char[], StringSplitOptions)` method:

```
string s = "15    Lore ipsum";
string result = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Answer (score 0):

`\s` stands for "whitespace character".

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp

Try `(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)$`

https://regex101.com/r/oH8qY6/1

Comment: ...or just put "\\s"